# Getting info from pickle file

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, pickle

I'am completly stuck and need your help! With opening and retriving information from pickle file. I think, i succed decoding it into `csr_matrix`:

```py
import pickle
import scipy.sparse as ss

with open('items_10000_matrix.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data_new = pickle.load(f,encoding = 'bytes')
print(ss.isspmatrix_csr(data_new))
lol = ss.csr_matrix.tocsr(data_new)
print(lol.get_shape)
```

But the error is: `indptr not found`.
Also, i had another tries before:
[CRS matrix:Shape not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186847/crs-matrixshape-not-found?noredirect=1#comment65720401_39186847).

File:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_NCpMplj2hY1AwTFBMZkNnMlU/view

Comment: I deleted my answer regarding `scipy.io` `mmread`/`mmwrite`. I think you have to ensure that you have the correct version of `scipy`. It should be the same as was used to generate your pickle file.

Comment: @vsminkov Very intresting, i'll check this out, thank you.